# Multiple comparisons in logic block

Tags: go

Should be a relatively straight forward question for those in the know.
I am trying to do the followig, but am new to golang.

```
if some_logic {

} else if some_var != "" && _, exists := Dict["somestring"] {

} else {

}
```

The `else if` block is the part of interest to me. 
I can't get it to compile when attempting multiple comparisons in the same logic block. Is this possible or do I need to change tact altogether?

**Update:**

I was able to solve functionally the problem above with the following addition;

```
else if _, exists := Dict["somestring"]; exists && some_var != ""
```

Comment: That is not possible. Use multiple `if` statements instead.

Comment: Actually it does seem possible. I was able to use this instead.
    else if _, exists := Dict["somestring"]; exists && some_var != ""

Comment: @icza please comment on the update to this post.

Comment: Yes, that's perfectly valid. What is not possible is to put a condition _before_ the short variable declaration, so it's not possible to avoid the short variable declaration based on a condition in a single `if` statement (utilizing the short-circuit nature of the `&&` evaluation).

Comment: @icza in which case rather than directing everyone to the other post which tackles a somewhat different angle. Why don't we un-mark this as a duplicate, restructure the question slightly and put the actual answer?